# Why would a sentient and super advanced species begin to think like humans over time?

Tags: science-fiction, space, space-colonization, civilization, psychology

I have a super advanced sentient species that is not human, and developing by itself on a planet. With such advancement, we expect them to think on a higher plane or at least in a different way to humans. And in the beginning they do. They live lives without issues of disease or religious conflicts or political issues or body image issues, etc affecting them. But then they come in contact with humans and a long drawn out conflict erupts between the two species.

What could happen for it to now begin thinking like humans, the very species it is fighting?

Comment: Why? Better still, why would humans not start to think like this species?

Comment: More information on how the species came into contact with humans would help.  Were super-species happily sitting on their planet and a human ship or fleet appeared in orbit and attacked?  Or did humans start flame wars with them once our ansibles could connect to the galactic social media provider Spacebook?  Also, how did the super species get to their super level - were they uplifted by Vorlons / Ancient Droyne or did they go through their own human-level stage of development?

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 , this species has gone through its own cycle of development and moved very ver far ahead. Yet it forgets / forgoes to think like what it has become and gets reduced to what it was once this conflict becomes. Could it be a disease inflicted from contact? Could it be something else like 
short-term priorities that this war brings? I am trying a lot of things, unable to come up with something.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second , because it is not about one species improving the other in this theme. It is more like both sets reducing to their primal instincts and worst versions. Even though one was supposed to have moved beyond that.

Comment: Dude, take a snort of this awesome drug. Then you will understand why those bipedal squishbags like 'pizza' and 'baywatch' so much. We need to replicate some sofas and beanbag chairs. Got any Cheetos? Hey, we should try 'smoking'

Comment: What do you mean by 'thinking like humans'? Are you talking about adopting the human culture and human stereotypes or something else? Also, how different those species from humans (biologically)? It would be impossible for species that are vastly different from humans in biology to start thinking like humans in many aspects.

Comment: @Otkin , Adopting human stereotypes and biases, lust for control or fighting, short term thinking.

Comment: What are those human stereotypes and biases? Do you have examples of universal stereotypes and biases? As for short term thinking, you know the joke -- the difference between Americans and Europeans is that Europeans believe that 100 miles is a long distance, while Americans believe that 100 years is a long time.

Comment: @AlexP , whatever be the type of biases, I tried to bring out in my question that the level of advancement the other species is at, it cannot be reached without forgoing those and attaining development. However, they r back to petty, or emotional, and other types of behavior. And I am trying to think of ways why.

Comment: Presumably the aliens see the human-style thinking as conferring some sort of advantage, and therefore adopt it in order to better achieve their goals.  (The problem that results is likely that what constitutes a short-term advantage for an individual alien also causes long-term disadvantages for the alien society as a whole; tragedy of the commons and all that).  The real question might be, why didn't the aliens ever discover that sort of reasoning before contact with humans?  What is it about the aliens that prevented them from doing so?

Comment: This reminds me of a story of Greg Bear where humanity is fighting a galactic-scale war and starts using clones of the most successful soldier archetypes, while the enemy species starts experimenting with humanity.

Comment: Maybe the aliens are just getting better at simulating humans so that they can predict what we're doing, all the better to wipe us out.

Comment: By 'human' thinking, do you not mean 'American thinking'? Earth has a very broad spread of cultural attributes.

Comment: By human thinking, I mean human thinking. For example purposes, we can take real life events around us that you think are holding us back or can be bettered and an advanced species would have left behind.

Comment: Then how do you explain the conflict? You are anthropomorphizing this species - forcing human traits onto them, making them in the image of humans, particularly Westernized humans, and you are asking us to do the same..

Comment: The conflict was of survival / dominance. More like a physical conflict. During the conflict, the modern species downgraded. So, I came asking for possible reasons to help explain it. Like crowdfunding ideas. So I wasnt forcing anything into the species. It was a blank canvas till now. Based on the ideas generated, I now know a few ideological explanations even though they sound weak.

Answer (score 10):

### A bunch of Reasons:

I can think of a number of reasons that an intellectual, detached species would devolve down to a more brutal, vicious state when confronted with humans.

- **Military Essentials**: Humans have the ability to kill other sentient beings, and issue orders for their machines to do so as well. I remember reading a novel where aliens sought out humans because they had lost the ability to kill, and they had a brutal enemy. To achieve the ability to kill intelligent life, they need to devolve.
- **Broken Faith**: The aliens have a Pollyanna attitude about the universe. If they are good and virtuous, everything will work out in the end. Then humans showed up, claiming they were better (while clearly inferior), nicer and more virtuous (while lying, cheating, and killing). Those who hold to this Pollyanna attitude are killed, while those who renounce it live. Those re-adopting ancient vicious practices fight off the humans, and those who accept the teachings of the humans end up being more like the humans - fanatical and very intelligent, willing to kill either get ahead or spread whatever faith they have come to follow.
- **Evolution**: Despite their apparent moral superiority, the aliens actually had a very primitive set of cultural practices centered around the traditional values of an agrarian society. They work together because they don't have a concept of lying and cheating (their ancestors thrived on cooperation). Now humans show up, introducing ideas like selfish interest, deception and greed. Suddenly there is a strong selective pressure for those aliens able to adopt these traits to out-compete their more peaceful neighbors. Kill your neighbor, steal his land, and take his wife as a second for yourself! Sure the humans are cheating them, but they mostly do it to themselves.
- **Imitation**: If you don't know how to cope with human insanity, who does? Humans, of course. They seek out humans and see how the humans deal with these unique human problems. To see how they should treat inferior humans as a species, they look to our racial interactions. When they see how we deal with criminals, they deal with humans (and increasing numbers of deviants in their own ranks) with executions and prison. Do humans use bioweapons? Humans have a complex "health care system" to deal with such things.
- **Undoing Domestication**: There is a theory that humans are part-way in undergoing a process of self-domestication, and that bonobos have essentially already done so to themselves. This process actually makes a species less intelligent but more passive by locking development in an earlier state. Under this theory, our ancestors were likely more intelligent and resourceful, but couldn't get along well and constantly fought. So in this scenario, humans are stuck half-way to domestication, but the aliens have gone all the way. Confronted with humans, the aliens must undo domestication (possibly by genetically re-engineering savagery) to make themselves stronger and more intelligent so as to confront the human menace.
- **OOPS! We turned ourselves into killers**: On that same note, the aliens knew they were once stronger and smarter and could kill as needed. The reasons for these things being removed from their species are lost to history. They recover the genes for these traits and add them back into their genomes (recovering what was lost). Only after they've done so do they realize they have opened Pandora's box and loosed all the evils of their old ways. This new generation lacks the skills to deal with such behaviors and abilities, and they regress socially even further than humans as a result.

Comment: Did you mean viscous practices?? I'm pretty sure it's a typo, but the human mind is remarkably jelly-like sometimes...

Comment: It's worth reading the Larry Niven story "Madness Has Its Place", where a post-conflict humanity suddenly needs to socially regress to a war footing in order to avoid destruction by the Kzinti.  Another book (not as good IMO) was Aggressor Six, where a team of humans were taught to think like their alien enemies in order to gain an advantage in anticipating their actions in the conflict.  Either or both fit with some of the points above.

Comment: @Otkin Thanks, spell-checking somehow turned vicious into viscous!

Answer (score 3):

> “If you know the enemy and know yourself, you need not fear the result
> of a hundred battles. If you know yourself but not the enemy, for
> every victory gained you will also suffer a defeat. If you know
> neither the enemy nor yourself, you will succumb in every battle.”
>
> ― Sun Tzu, The Art of War

In order to fully know your enemy and thus to defeat them, you must be able to think like them or at the very least to be able to simulate their thoughts to a sufficient degree so as to be able to predict their actions.

Answer (score 1):

### Dictatorships are fragile.

The alien race formed a dictatorship, with everything being managed from a central hub with precise order and control for all to keep them in line. It worked fine for centuries, with their huge production powers being enough to handle any problems.

There were outsiders with body issues, religions, politics and such, but they were on the fringes of society and no one cared about them much.

When the war happened the over centralized society had some severe fuck ups and shocks. The members no longer trusted the central leadership to react well to their local situations, with core functions prioritized over their homelands, and severe tactical mistakes from a lack of creativity, quick responses, and order.

However, the outsiders did great, and their creativity and lack of trust of the central government meant they succeeded. As such, they became the new nucleus's of alliances to fight the humans. If thinking like humans works, why not do it more?

Answer (score 1):

**The aliens are absolutely nuts for human TV and movies.**

[image: i love lucy]

https://www.closerweekly.com/posts/i-love-lucy-behind-the-scene-details-classic-tv-show/

Humans are hard to get along with.  But dang they make great shows!  The aliens acquire the vast trove of human TV and movies and they are hooked.  Aficionados of various characters adopt mannerisms and catch phrases from those characters.  Situations in TV and movies are found to have analogs in the doings of the aliens.  Aliens approach each other and issues in their culture with the mannerisms learned from TV and movies.   The aliens are infected by human culture.

This would be very fun to write and even more fun as a TV show.  Almost all the aliens have a favorite character.  There would be an alien Ricky and in one episode it encounters another alien Ricky.

Answer (score 0):

You've already modeled this life form as "humans on another planet". You do this because you yourself are human, and you model them that way subconsciously.

Let's look at it objectively. They are *multiple*, but unlike bees or ants they have individual personalities (or at least, like humans, perceive themselves to have individual personalities). They are social. That is, they don't all run off territorial-like and become recluses on their own mountaintops (with the exception of mating season, when they seek out others).

You're basically just doing an exercise in tropes. The trope is that they are utopian. No anorexia or religious dogma or genocides. But, much like some ancient morality plan, once they come into contact with humans they become contaminated by it, until they too fall from grace.

If you need a good reason though, why, then it's just that they were already practically identical to humans before you even started to ask the question.

You could strive to make them more alien, but if you succeed they won't seem utopian anymore. Instead, they'll seem totalitarian, terrifying. Maybe even demonic. So I don't know how to repair your premise to get anything out of that you'd find satisfying.

Comment: Can I make them AI? But would AI in any case fall into human habits?

Comment: I don't have a problem making the aliens totalitarian. In that case, falling into human habits would be them getting confused or distracted or not being able to pull everyone in one direction. So that would be another spin on "getting them to think like human" trope. The question still remains "why / how"?

Comment: @mukul215 Why would AI ever have distinct, individual agents? It would be singular, most likely. Even AI invented by some monkeys like us where there could be many individuals might find itself inclined to merge/fuse into a singular mind, and its digital nature would make that a trivial accomplishment. There are many subtle and profound philosophical lessons to be learned here, I think, but none that rescue your premise. Turtledove's The Race did something like what you want, but then they too started out *very* human-like, so there wasn't much to disrupt.

Comment: one last thing. Can the event in my story happen before the AI has reached that ultimate stage? Like it is super advanced but on its way to melding into a singular being, hence there are still cracks. Which it succumbs to?

Comment: @mukul215 An AI will never think like a human. The difference between humans and AI is too great. A lot of our (human) thinking has to do with the fact that we are biological creatures with short lives and specific needs dictated by our biology. An AI does not have the same limitations. Perhaps, if an AI was built using organic technologies you could make it think more like organic beings. But in this case, you need to ask whether the AI is still AI.

Comment: @Otkin Given that the first AIs will likely be modeled on humans, they will be like humans for a very long time. Perhaps as long as 30-40 minutes (practically an eternity). That's more than enough time for the rise and fall of many AI civilizations.

Comment: @JohnO A sentient and sapient AI will most likely be able to *imitate* humans. A less advanced and less intelligent AI can *be made to imitate* humans. But they cannot be *like humans* because they are not humans: They are not organic, they do not grow up as humans in human societies, they do not have the same biological needs as humans, etc. Humans can imitate other species to a certain extent, but we cannot become other species. Even humans raised by other species do not become other species.

Answer (score 0):

### They won't. Unless those aliens are human.

Humans think the way they think because they are biological intelligent beings that evolved on Earth, have two biological sexes (more or less), and share a common history.

A lot of our stereotypes, biases, traditions, cognitive shortcuts, and so on are related to our evolution and history as species. It is hard to say how much is 'wired' and how much is a result of socialisation: Different schools of psychology will give you different answers. However, the absolute majority of them will agree that most of our behaviour is related to physical reality (environment, our biology, etc.).

The best your aliens can do is an *imitation* of humans. I would not be surprised if much of this imitation were superficial. Moreover, it is very likely that the meaning behind this imitation will be completely different from humans.

---

There is one possible solution: Your aliens are capable of morphing themselves and their environment. Over time **they do not start thinking like humans, they become humans**. This is similar to the Ray Bradbury's [*Dark They Were, and Golden-Eyed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_They_Were,_and_Golden-Eyed).